# match by id and take average in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Match by id and then return average of val from 'data'

**collection1**

```
[{
        "_id" : 1,
        "data" : [
                {
                        "val" : 2,
                },
               {
                        "val" : 4,
                },{
                        "val" : 6,
                }
               ]
},
{
        "_id" : 2,
        "data" : [
                {
                        "val" : 99,
                }
               ]
}]
```

If my id is 1 then average of val is 4

Answer (score 2):

The [`$avg` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) is probably what you are looking for. In your situation you also need to slightly transform the array to extract the numbers, something along the lines of:

```
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "average": {
        "$avg": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$data",
            "in": "$$this.val"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[Playground example here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aP8BtpSYMNW)

---

**Edit** Turns out the `$map` isn't needed here. Simply referring to the field name apparently generates the input array as expected. So the above can be simplified to:

```
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "average": {
        "$avg": "$data.val"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[Updated playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/h_2s8grwKmL)